# block script php in a img tag

Tags: php, image, header

i have a php  script to redirect users, like this:

```
<?php
// my code
header( "location: $url" );
?>
```

should work only in a `<a href="http://domain.com/redirect.php?id=1">` tag

**is it possible to block this redirect script from running in a img tag?**

for example if the script is called in this way < img src="http://domain.com/redirect.php?id=1" />

can i add a php check for header and block the execution?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, you can't. Also you can do some JavaScript, i write you an example in jQuery.

```
<a href="#" class="redirect">Link</a>

$('a.redirect').click(function(){
    document.location = 'http://domain.com/redirect.php';
});
```

This way only links will redirect which have `.redirect` class. Hope this helps.

Comment: thx, but it dosent help in my case because the "a href" or "img src" tag is in email html code, so i need to check with php, there is no way to check with the **accept header** ?